# Highlighting specific data points for parallel coordinates plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, scikit-learn, yellowbrick

I'm looking for help to highlight/color particular data points on the parallel coordinates plot. I can't seem to find a way that work.

Essentially, I want to plot all the data as below, and then take, e.g., index [0, 1, 2] of the data points and color them a third color to highlight them (and if possible also make them thicker?) Any suggestions?

```
from sklearn import datasets
from yellowbrick.features import ParallelCoordinates

iris = datasets.load_iris()
X = iris.data[:, :]
y = iris.target

features = ['sepal_length', 'sepal_width', 'petal_length', 'petal_width']
classes = ['Iris-setosa', 'Iris-versicolor', 'Iris-virginica']
title = "Plot over Iris Data"

# Instantiate the visualizer
visualizer = ParallelCoordinates(
    classes=classes, features=features, fast=False, alpha=.40, title=title)

# Fit the visualizer and display it
visualizer.fit_transform(X, y)
visualizer.finalize()  # creates title, legend, etc.

visualizer.ax.tick_params(labelsize=22)  # change size of tick labels
visualizer.ax.title.set_fontsize(30)  # change size of title

for text in visualizer.ax.legend_.texts:  # change size of legend texts
     text.set_fontsize(20)

visualizer.fig.tight_layout()  # fit all texts nicely into the surrounding figure
visualizer.fig.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, [`ParallelCoordinates.draw()`](https://www.scikit-yb.org/en/latest/_modules/yellowbrick/features/pcoords.html#ParallelCoordinates) iterates the datapoints in order. Hence, the child `Line2D` instances of `visualizer.ax` will follow the order of the data. Hence, you can do:

```
from sklearn import datasets
from yellowbrick.features import ParallelCoordinates

# New code ----------------------
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
special_lines = [0, 1, 2]
# Put any property you want here.
special_properties = {'linestyle': '--', 'color': 'k', 
                      'linewidth': 5, 'zorder': float('inf'), 
                      'alpha': 1}
# End of new code ---------------

iris = datasets.load_iris()
X = iris.data[:, :]
y = iris.target

features = ['sepal_length', 'sepal_width', 'petal_length', 'petal_width']
classes = ['Iris-setosa', 'Iris-versicolor', 'Iris-virginica']
title = "Plot over Iris Data"

# Instantiate the visualizer
visualizer = ParallelCoordinates(
    classes=classes, features=features, fast=False, alpha=.40, title=title)

# Fit the visualizer and display it
visualizer.fit_transform(X, y)

# New code ----------------------
for line in [visualizer.ax.get_lines()[i] for i in special_lines]:
    plt.setp(line, **special_properties)
# End of new code ---------------

visualizer.finalize()  # creates title, legend, etc.

visualizer.ax.tick_params(labelsize=22)  # change size of tick labels
visualizer.ax.title.set_fontsize(30)  # change size of title

for text in visualizer.ax.legend_.texts:  # change size of legend texts
     text.set_fontsize(20)
        
visualizer.fig.tight_layout()  # fit all texts nicely into the surrounding figure
visualizer.fig.show()
```

Result:

[image]

Please note that the fact that lines are added in-order is not written in the documentation, it's just how it is implemented. Hence, it could be (even though I don't expect it) that they will change this behavior in future updates. A safer way would be to manually check whether the line's data matches the transformed data used by the visualizer. Note that we **need** to use the transformed data in general, because `ParallelCoordinates` also implements a normaliser. It's not your case, but in general we should do so:

```
# Perform AFTER visualizer.fit_transform(X, y).
import numpy as np

transformed_data = list(visualizer.transform(X[special_lines, :]))
for line in visualizer.ax.get_lines():
    for i, arr in enumerate(transformed_data[:]): 
        if np.array_equal(arr, line.get_data()[1]):
            plt.setp(line, **special_properties)
            break
```

Comment: This is great, and really helped me understand, thanks!